How can i do a rewind button for my Chess game code? C++
I am doing a little project of chess in C++ for my homework. The problem is i don`t know how to copy the dynamic array of my last move (So for example white do an illegal move but have a copy of the board so i rewind and white go again)
Here is the full code of my program
.
.
.
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



wstring  board[8][8] = {
    L"\033[31m♜ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♞ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♝ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♚ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♛ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♝ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♞ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♜ \033[0m",
    L"\033[31m♙ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♙ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♙ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♙ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♙ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♙ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♙ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♙ \033[0m",
    L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ",
    L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ",
    L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ",
    L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ",
    L"♙ ", L"♙ ", L"♙ ", L"♙ ", L"♙ ", L"♙ ", L"♙ ", L"♙ ",
    L"♖ ", L"♘ ", L"♗ ", L"♔ ", L"♕ ", L"♗ ", L"♘ ", L"♖ "
};
wstring* backboard = &board[8][8];
void SaveBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            backboard = &board[8][8];
        }
    }
}
void Back() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
             board[8][8] = *backboard;
        }
    }
}
// board printing
void printBoard() {
    wcout << L"   A B C D E F G H" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        wcout << 8 - i << L" |";
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            wcout << board[i][j];
        }
        wcout << L"| " << 8 - i << endl;
    }
    wcout << L"   A B C D E F G H" << endl;
}


// Moving 
bool movePiece(string from, string to) {
    
    int fromX = from[0] - 'A';    
    int fromY = 8 - (from[1] - '0'); 
    int toX = to[0] - 'A';
    int toY = 8 - (to[1] - '0');

    
    if (fromX < 0 || fromX >= 8 || fromY < 0 || fromY >= 8 || toX < 0 || toX >= 8 || toY < 0 || toY >= 8) {
        wcout << L"Wrong coordinates!" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    wstring piece = board[fromY][fromX];

    SaveBoard();

    board[toY][toX] = piece;
    board[fromY][fromX] = L"  ";

    return true;
}


int main() {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT); // Setting for Unicode symbols
    SetConsoleCP(1251);     // u don`t need this since i translated everything
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleMode;
    ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
    string from, to;

    while (true) {
        printBoard();

        wcout << L"Move piece or use back/exit: ";
        cin >> from;

        if (from == "exit") break;
        if (from == "back") {
            Back();
            wcout << L"Returned." << endl;
            continue;
        
        }
        else {
            wcout << L"Not Returned. Try again." << endl;
        }
        cin >> to;

        if (!movePiece(from, to)) {
            wcout << L"Move didn`t work. Try again." << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

What i want to have - moving pieces within the board(every piece can move wherever they want) and a rewind command returning the game to the previous move.
I am sorry if something is confusing but this is my first overflow post and i am not an english major
I tried working with the arrays, but what i happened to deal was after back the board just dissappear, all the empty space and the pieces
wstring  board[8][8] = {
    L"\033[31m♜ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♞ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♝ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♚ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♛ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♝ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♞ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♜ \033[0m",
    L"\033[31m♙ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♙ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♙ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♙ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♙ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♙ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♙ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♙ \033[0m",
    L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ",
    L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ",
    L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ",
    L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ",
    L"♙ ", L"♙ ", L"♙ ", L"♙ ", L"♙ ", L"♙ ", L"♙ ", L"♙ ",
    L"♖ ", L"♘ ", L"♗ ", L"♔ ", L"♕ ", L"♗ ", L"♘ ", L"♖ "
};

So this is the board and i had to add colors for the project, which resulted in the problem of the the whole board disappearing using "back". I am pretty sure i fixed it by
SetConsoleMode;
ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;


I think instead of wstring* backboard = &board[8][8]; you want simply wstring backboard = board[8][8];, and then in SaveBoard()'s loop you want to do backboard[i][j] = board[i][j]; and similarly in Back(), board[i][j] = backboard[i][j];.

Put your board state into a struct or class. Then you can use the assignment operator to save and restore the board state.

@СергійДегтярьов now we're talking about a bug we can't see.  The comment from HAL9000 is valid.

Consider using the Command pattern so that every action you perform adds the corresponding "undo" action to the stack of recent activity.  Then you'll be able to undo as many times as you want.

The Command Pattern is indeed the popular solution for undo/redo functionality.  Although patterns are typically objects, and it looks like you aren't yet familiar with making classes and objects.

wstring* backboard = &board[8][8]; creates a pointer to a single wstring outside of the board and board[8][8] = *backboard; dereferences that pointer and tries to assign this non-existing wstring back to the same single wstring outside the board.  You have undefined behavior.

Recommendation: Switch from the Error List tab to the Output Tab. Not only is the plain text diagnostic in the Output Tab easier to paste into Stack Overflow, it also often contains extra information left out of the simplified and formatted diagnostic shown on the Error List.

Keep a record of moves. Every move can be represented by 2 numbers (n <64)representing from and to houses. Simplest would be std::vector<move_data> game_moves;. Moves at even indice belong to white and odd indice belong to black. A push_back on the vector - alongside updating the board - makes a move. pop_back on the vector - after updating the board regarding game_moves.back() - will revert the move. You need more info on the vector - of course - to reflect capturing, promotion, en-passant and other dynamic game info; so the simplistic std::pair is not good as the move_data.

Although keeping a stack of full copies of the board is possible (and I encourage to refactor your code along the lines of the other answer anyway) - it's not necessary just to undo moves.
How much changes on the board from one move to the next? A piece P moves from position X to position Y and maybe takes piece Q in the process. Two pieces and two positions.
With some extra effort to capture en passant and castling moves, all you need is to keep a stack of objects describing these moves, and then to write the code to reverse a given move.
NB. This object is equivalent to the Command pattern mentioned in comments. You don't really need a full implementation of that pattern though, especially if you're not yet comfortable writing classes and polymorphic class hierarchies. You can just record the information in a plain-old-data struct and write a single function to reverse it.

First, I suggest that you put your wstring[8][8] inside a class that handles a single board, let's call it Board and then add some functions to access the array. While you're at it, you can use std::array<std::array<std::wstring, 8>, 8> to get some member functions that may come in handy.
Example:
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

class Board {
public:
    using row_type = std::array<std::wstring, 8>;
    using board_type = std::array<row_type, 8>;

    Board() = default;
    Board(board_type&& init) : m_data(std::move(init)) {}

    row_type& operator[](std::size_t Y) { // add const qualified if needed
        return m_data[Y];
    }

    std::size_t size() const { return m_data.size(); }

    void print(std::wostream& os = std::wcout) const {
        os << L"   A B C D E F G H\n";
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
            os << size() - i << L" |";
            for (auto& str : m_data[i]) {
                os << str;
            }
            os << L"| " << size() - i << L'\n';
        }
        os << L"   A B C D E F G H\n";
    }

private:
    board_type m_data{};
};

This gives you a Board type with a subscript operator to access elements in the 2d array, a size function and a print function that prints to the screen by default.
To the actual question:
In order to go back, you could push() each Board onto a std::stack. If you need to go back a step, you copy what's on top() of the stack and then pop() that element from the stack. However, for this purpose I find using a std::vector more convenient since it can resize() itself if we want to reset the game to the initial state and a few other things.
I've put your original functions in a class called Chess to hide implementation details like SaveBoard() etc. from the user. When instantiated, it'll copy the static initial_board to the non-static member variable m_boards, which is our std::vector<Board> that will act as a stack. The initial_board will be the first board in this stack.
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <stack>

class Chess {
    inline static const Board initial_board{{{
        {L"\033[31m♜ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♞ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♝ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♚ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♛ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♝ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♞ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♜ \033[0m"},
        {L"\033[31m♙ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♙ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♙ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♙ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♙ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♙ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♙ \033[0m", L"\033[31m♙ \033[0m"},
        {L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  "},
        {L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  "},
        {L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  "},
        {L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  ", L"  "},
        {L"♙ ", L"♙ ", L"♙ ", L"♙ ", L"♙ ", L"♙ ", L"♙ ", L"♙ "},
        {L"♖ ", L"♘ ", L"♗ ", L"♔ ", L"♕ ", L"♗ ", L"♘ ", L"♖ "}
    }}};

public:
    Chess() : m_boards{ initial_board } {} // put the initial board on the stack

    void Reset() {
        m_boards.resize(1); // remove all but the initial board
    }

    std::size_t getMoveNumber() const {
        return m_boards.size();
    }

    bool Back() {
        // if there's only the initial board on the stack, don't do anything
        if (m_boards.size() == 1) return false;
        m_boards.pop_back(); // remove last Board
        return true;
    }

    // accessors to the current Board:
    Board& getBoard() { return m_boards.back(); }
    const Board& getBoard() const { return m_boards.back(); }

    void printBoard() const {
        getBoard().print();
    }

    bool movePiece(std::string from, std::string to) {
        // check that positions have exactly 2 chars each
        if (from.size() != 2 || to.size() != 2) return false;

        std::size_t fromX = std::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(from[0])) - 'A';
        std::size_t fromY = 8 - (from[1] - '0');
        std::size_t toX = std::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(to[0])) - 'A';
        std::size_t toY = 8 - (to[1] - '0');

        if(fromX >= 8 || fromY >= 8 || toX >= 8 || toY >= 8) {
            std::wcout << L"Wrong coordinates!\n";
            return false;
        }
        
        SaveBoard();

        auto& board = getBoard();
        board[toY][toX] = board[fromY][fromX];
        board[fromY][fromX] = L"  ";

        return true;
    }

private:
    void SaveBoard() {
        // just copy the current board and put it on the stack
        m_boards.push_back(getBoard());
    }

    std::vector<Board> m_boards;
};

As you can see, when you now call Back() it'll just remove the last entry put on the stack (if there is an entry to remove from there).
Using it could then look like this:
int main() {
    // ... your initialization stuff ...
    std::string from, to;
    Chess game; // create a game instance

    while(true) {
        game.printBoard();
        std::wcout << L"Move number " << game.getMoveNumber() << L".\n";
        std::wcout << L"Move piece or use back/reset/exit: ";
        std::cin >> from;

        if(from == "exit") break;

        if (from == "reset") {
            game.Reset();
            std::wcout << L"Restarting game.\n";
            continue;
        }

        if(from == "back") {
            if (game.Back()) {
                std::wcout << L"Returned.\n";
            }
            else {
                std::wcout << L"Already at first move.\n";
            }
            continue;
        }
        std::wcout << L"Move to: ";
        std::cin >> to;

        if(!game.movePiece(from, to)) {
            std::wcout << L"Move didn`t work. Try again.\n";
        }
    }
}


In the end I used this answer by @"500 - Internal Server Error":

I think instead of wstring* backboard = &board[8][8]; you want simply wstring backboard = board[8][8];, and then in SaveBoard()'s loop you want to do backboard[i][j] = board[i][j]; and similarly in Back(), board[i][j] = backboard[i][j];.

It was what I asked for and what I wanted. Thank you for the answers.

wstring backboard = board[8][8]; has undefined behavior and is not a solution to anything
